# I thought of it too

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

> I thought of it too

Is it the phrase native speakers use to confirm they have given a thought to something? What are the other possible phrases?

For example:

> -- We need to repair the window.
>
> -- Yeah, I thought of it too.

Comment: *I'd thought about that; I thought it as well.*

Comment: Can you provide some examples and wider context?

Comment: @laugh That occurred to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I thought of it too" means that I also came up with an idea. It tends to imply some originality of thought.

"I thought about it too" means that I also considered something. It tends to imply that an idea was suggested and and we both considered it.

To think of something is creative. To think about something is contemplative. To think of is to have an idea. To think about is to consider an idea.

Comment: Shall we say "I have thought about it too"?

Comment: In the case of your example sentence, "We need to repair the window," yes, the response would be "I have thought about it too".

Comment: @Eugene - Perhaps even more natural: [_I had that same thought_](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=%22I+had+that+same+thought%22).